# n vertex graph without isolated vertices - maximum vertex degree

Tags: graph-theory

Provided there is a $n$-vertex graph without isolated vertices which is disconnected, prove that the maximum vertex degree does not exceed $n-3$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I do not know how to work it out. There was no context provided just the question. Thanks for your advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph has at least 2 connected components, which have (since there is no isolated vertex) at least two vertices each. Hence the maximal size of a connected component is given by $n-2$. The maximal degree of a vertex cannot exceed one minus the size of the connected component it belongs to, which in this case is at most $n-3$.